# How can I fix no line found error when using scanner in my code?

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner

I keep getting this exception when I run my code:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Unknown Source)
at BattleshipCheck.generateGrid(BattleshipCheck.java:60)
```

here's my code:

```
public static int[][] generateGrid(Scanner in, int gridSize) {
    int[][] grid = new int[gridSize][gridSize];
    while(in.hasNextLine()) {
    in.nextLine();
    in.nextLine();
    String[] currentLine = in.nextLine().split("\\s+");
    for (int row = 0; row < gridSize; row++) {
        for (int column = 0; column < gridSize; column++) {
             grid[row][column] = Integer.parseInt(currentLine[column]);
        }
    }
    }
    return grid;


}
```

I'm trying to start reading from the third row so I used .nextLine twice and I'm thinking that's where my problem lies but I'm not sure how to fix it

Comment: Only call `nextLine()` once per iteration? In your loop you check to see if theres another line, but then you call `nextLine()` three times (Two of them just throw away the results too)

Comment: @GBlodgett when I do that it reads in the second line instead for the array

Comment: What do you mean? If you want to skip the first two lines, move the two calls to `nextLine()` outside of the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to start at the third row, call nextLine() before the while-Loop, not inside of it. Once you're at the last line, you try skipping two more lines, which dont exist. You'll also have to check whether the file actually has three lines before skipping two lines.

```
public static int[][] generateGrid(Scanner in, int gridSize) {
int[][] grid = new int[gridSize][gridSize];

if(in.hasNextLine())in.nextLine();
if(in.hasNextLine())in.nextLine();

while(in.hasNextLine()) {
String[] currentLine = in.nextLine().split("\\s+");
for (int row = 0; row < gridSize; row++) {
    for (int column = 0; column < gridSize; column++) {
         grid[row][column] = Integer.parseInt(currentLine[column]);
    }
}
}
return grid;
```

}

Comment: @Rose Note that this will produce incorrect results. It will assign the last row to every row in the grid.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are ignoring the data in the file. It tells you how many lines there are. Also, there is no need for a `while` loop.

```
public static int[][] generateGrid(Scanner in) {
    // Get gridSize from file
    int gridSize = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
    int[][] grid = new int[gridSize][gridSize];

    // Not sure what 2nd line is for
    // I'm guessing it is the number of ships followed
    // by the size of each ship
    in.nextLine();

    for (int row = 0; row < gridSize; row++) {
        // Move this here
        String[] currentLine = in.nextLine().split("\\s+");
        for (int column = 0; column < gridSize; column++) {
             grid[row][column] = Integer.parseInt(currentLine[column]);
        }
    }

    return grid;
}
```

You still need to add error checking in case the file is malformed. Although I would leave as-is an let it throw an exception if there is a problem. Let the calling function deal with it.

Answer (score -1):

```
int i=0;
public static int[][] generateGrid(Scanner in, int gridSize) {
    int[][] grid = new int[gridSize][gridSize];
    while(in.hasNextLine()) {
        if(++i < 2) {
            in.nextLine();
            continue;
        }
        String[] currentLine = in.nextLine().split("\\s+");
        for (int row = 0; row < gridSize; row++) {
            for (int column = 0; column < gridSize; column++) {
                 grid[row][column] = Integer.parseInt(currentLine[column]);
            }
        }
    }
    return grid;


}
```